# share iframe with specific content

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink, sharing

Lets say i have a website called http://123.com.

The index.html page of the website contains an iframe called theframe.
i have three different page (1.html, 2.html, 3.html) for the iframe content and they will be displayed when i click specific button in the site. The default content of the iframe is 1.html.

My question is, if i need to share http://123.com with 2.html or 3.html displayed on the iframe, how should i write the link on facebook/blog/IM to share? Is there a way without modifying the website?

Thank you.

Comment: I am assuming that the specific button calls a java script on the page which then loads the iframe with the correct iframe. If that is the case no one can help you till you paste the code for the same. If it si a form submission then you can pass the same parameters via the url.

Comment: In my case, there is no java script on the page, just plain html. Is there a way to do that only by modifying the link?

Answer (score 0):

you have hard coded value in iframe src

use querystring

make a parameter named `dstntn` palce in your url

```
http://123.com/?dstntn=your_url
```

and then get it in a var by $_REQUEST['dstntn'];

and give var to iframe src

then change iframe  by changing   dstntn value by 1.html || 2.html

NOTE: read encoded and decoded form for query string  i think dots are not acceptable

Comment: sorry, but http://123.com/?dstntn=your_url means it has index.php instead of index.html? i don't want that. i don't want to change the website. is there a way by just modifying the link i share?

Comment: no iam saying your if you pass the 2.html in dstntn query string it will put that address in iframe with help of js

Comment: i write "http://123.com/?dstntn=http://123.com/2.html" but it still opens 1.html on its iframe. sorry i don't understand yet, would you explain it more detailed? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Principally, you can make headings in h1 or h2 just above the iframe and have the page hashed-index the headings as URL to be shared. I think your button just need to also load those different headings in each next/ previous click. You'll find a way

Making life easier...just use this chrome extension to copy text (which is the headings) as URL value:

[Copy Link Text Chrome Extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-link-text/loeniidbmeohdlmipbpkfmiogbcncibh)

And as for sharing URL method, any social media share generator can do it, such as as  this one:

[Share Link Creator](https://www.websiteplanet.com/webtools/sharelink/)

Best of luck.